# How can I get declared classes in method?

Tags: java, android, reflection, classloader

This is Test class.

```
package com.reflection;

import com.reflection.test.A

public class Main {
  public void setA() {
    A a = new A();
  }
}
```

Then, I used `ClassLoader` for accessing and manipulating classes, fields, methods, and constructors as the code below

```
Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.reflection.Main");
```

Actually I really want to get `A` class by using `cls` and already tried to use `getDeclaredClasses` and `getClasses` but the result was nothing.

Comment: @Jobin field should be declared out of `setA` though? A a; public void setA() { a = new A(); } like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with pure Java reflection. Reflection will let you look at classes and their members, but not at the code inside a method.

The easiest thing to do is probably to do `javap -v` somewhere in the build process, parse the output for qualified class names and store them in a property file somewhere.

The harder version is to use a byte code tool like asm or ByteBuddy, write a visitor over all instructions in your class and store all classes from all instructions in a Map. While this is theoretically the elegant approach, it will probably be a nightmare.

Comment: thank so much for your amazing answer. i'm really looking forward to a solution, but I can not find any clue.

Comment: I really appreciated ur help !